# htaccess redirect while URL contains questionmark, dot and comma

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Some old website is using URL like:

```
 domain.com/website?content=http//www.seconddomain.com/view/info/page.html?www.domain.com,0,123,444,123
```

I would like to make redirection on new page, something like:

```
 Redirect 301 domain.com/website?content=http//www.seconddomain.com/view/info/page.html?www.domain.com,0,123,444,123  /category/page-name.html
```

But that doesn't work, so I would have to use something else. What would be the best way to do it? I just need some full URL with various characters (like questionmark, dot, comma) to be redirected to new URL which I would write.

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^content=http//www.seconddomain.com/view/info/page\.html
RewriteRule ^website$ /category/page-name.html [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I tried it like this, but this is just ignored, redirect is not made.